# Create2 gives different addresses on different networks

Tags: contract-deployment, rinkeby, create2, goerli

I'm trying to deploy a contract on two networks with the create2 method. I'm using same arguments in Goerli and Rinkeby, however I'm still getting two different addresses for the same contract.

Here is the code I'm using, [Extracted from another tutorial](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/create2/):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Factory {
    // Returns the address of the newly deployed contract
    function deploy(
        address _owner,
        uint256 _foo,
        bytes32 _salt
    ) public payable returns (address) {
        // This syntax is a newer way to invoke create2 without assembly, you just need to pass salt
        // https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#salted-contract-creations-create2
        return address(new SimpleContract{salt: _salt}(_owner, _foo));
    }
}

contract SimpleContract {
    address public owner;
    uint256 public salt;

    constructor(address _owner, uint256 _salt) payable {
        owner = _owner;
        salt = _salt;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the transaction hashes where the contract were deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Is your factory address the same on both networks ?

Verify that the factory address is the same on both networks and you are working with the same salt on both networks